Mendelson Introduction to Topology Chapter 2 Metric spaces Page 46 Question 7- basis for neighbourhood system at $a.$
Definitions: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $a\in X.$ For $\delta>0,$ the open ball $B(a;\delta):= \{x\in X: d(a,x) < \delta\}.\ \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ means the Cartesian product $X_1\times X_2\times \ldots \times X_n.$ A subset $N$ of $X$ is called a neighbourhood of $a$ if there is a $\delta>0$ such that $B(a;\delta) \subset N.$ A collection $\mathscr{B}_{a}$ of neighbourhoods of $a$ is called a basis for the neighbourhood system at $a$ if every neighbourhood $N$ of $a$ contains some element $B$ of $\mathscr{B}_{a}.$

Let $(X_1,d_1),\ (X_2,d_2),\ \ldots,\ (X_n,d_n)$ be metric spaces and
convert $X=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ into a metric space
$(X,d)$ in the standard manner. This means
$d(x,y):=\displaystyle\max_{1\leq i\leq n} d_i(x_i,y_i).$ Prove that
an open ball in $(X,d)$ is the product of open balls from $X_1,
 X_2,\ldots, X_n$ respectively. Let $a_i\in X_i,\ i=1,2,\ldots, n,\ $
and let $\mathscr{B}_{a_i}$ be a basis for the neighbourhood system at
$a_i.$ Let $\mathscr{B}_{a}$ be the collection of all sets of the form
$B_1\times B_2\times\ldots B_n,\ B_i\in\mathscr{B}_{a_i}.$ Prove that
$\mathscr{B}_{a}$ is a basis for the neighbourhood system at
$a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n).$


I found the first question straightforward, and I have an answer for the second question, but I am not sure my answer is correct, and even if it is, I think it is convoluted and I am missing something simpler. Any suggestions for improvement are welcome. My answers:

Answer to the first question: Let $a\in X.$ An open ball around $a$ with radius $\delta$ is the set $B(a;\delta):= \{ x\in X: d(a,x)<\delta\} = \left\{x\in\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n X_i: \max_{1\leq i\leq n} d_i(a_i,x_i)<\delta\right\} = \left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n X_i:d_i(a_i,x_i)<\delta\ \forall\ i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\right\}=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n\{ x_i\in X_i: d_i(a_i,x_i)<\delta\}=\prod_{i=1}^n B_i(a_i,\delta).$

Answer to the second question: We can show two things: $1)\ N\in\mathscr{B}_{a}$ $\implies N$ is a nbhd of $a.$ (This would establish that $\mathscr{B}_{a}$ is in fact a collection of neigbourhoods. And $2)\ $ If $N$ is a nbhd of $a\in X,$ then $\exists\ N'\in\mathscr{B}_{a}$ such that $N'\subset N.$ (This would establish that $\mathscr{B}_{a}$ is a basis for the system of neighbourhoods at $a.$)
$1)\ $ Let $N\in\mathscr{B}_{a}.$ Then $\exists\ B_i\in\mathscr{B}_{a_i}$ such that $N=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n B_i.$ For each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}:\ $ since $B_i$ is a nbhd of $a_i,\ \exists\ \delta_i>0$ such that $B(a_i;\delta_i)\subset B_i.$ Let $\delta_j:= \displaystyle\min_{1\leq i\leq n} \{\delta_i\}.$ Then $B(a,\delta_j)=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n B(a_i;\delta_j)\subset\prod_{i=1}^n B_i=N.$ Since there is an open ball around $a$ which is a subset of $N,$ it follows that $N$ is a nbhd of $a.$
$2)\ $ By the definition of nbhd, since $N$ is a nbhd of $a,\ \exists\ $ an open ball $B(a;\delta)$ for some $\delta>0,$ such that $B(a;\delta)\subset N.$ From our answer to the first question, $B(a;\delta)=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n B_i(a_i,\delta).$ Now, $B(a_i,\delta)$ is a nbhd of $a_i$ (for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}),$ and so, since $\mathscr{B}_{a_i}$ is a basis for the nbhd system at $a_i$ (for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}),\ \exists\ B_i\in\mathscr{B}_{a_i}$ such that $B_i\subset B(a_i;\delta) $ (for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}).$ Thus $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n B_i \in\mathscr{B}_{a},$ and $(1)\implies \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n B_i$ is a nbhd of $a.$ Note also that $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n B_i\subset \prod_{i=1}^n B(a_i,\delta)=B(a;\delta)\subset N.\ $ So we may take $N'=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n B_i,$ and we are done.

I added the tag "solution-verification" which you actually ask for. From the tag description: "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

I think your proof is the standard one and it is well written. Why are you doubts that it is not okay?

I was unsure I needed to prove $1).$ And I just wasn't sure my proof to $2)$ was correct, and if it is correct it seems a bit verbose. I'm a bit rusty when it comes to proofs in topology/metric spaces.
